# MarkLogic: Move document from one directory to another on some condition

Tags: java, marklogic, nosql

I'm new to MarkLogic and trying to implement following scenario with its Java API:

1. For each user I'll have two directories, something like:

   1.1. user1/xmls/recent/

   1.2. user1/xmls/archived/
2. When user is doing something with his xml - it's put to the "recent" directory;
3. When user is doing something with his next xml and "recent" directory is full (e.g. has some amount of documents, let's say 20) - the oldest document is moved to the "archived" directory;
4. User can request all documents from the "recent" directory and should get no more than 20 records;
5. User can remove something from the "recent" directory manually; In this case, if it had 20 documents, after deleting one it must have 19;
6. User can do something with his xmls simultaneously and "recent" directory should never become bigger than 20 entries.

Questions are:

1. In order to properly handle simultaneous adding of xmls to the "recent" directory, should I block whole "recent" directory when adding new entry (to actually add it, check if there are more than 20 records after adding, select the oldest 21st one and move it to the "archived" directory and do all these steps atomically)? How can I do it?
2. Any suggestions on how to implement this via Java API?
3. Is it possible to change document's URI (e.g. replace "recent" with "archived" in my case)?
4. Should I consider using MarkLogic's collections here?

I'm open to any suggestions and comments (as I said I'm new to MarkLogic and maybe my thoughts on how to handle described scenario are completely wrong).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can achieve atomicity of a sequence of transactions using Multi-Statement Transactions (MST)
2. It is possible to MST from the Java API: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_79848
3. It's not possible to change a URI. However, it is possible to use an MST to delete the old document and reinsert a new one using the new URI in one an atomic step. This would have the same effect.
4. Possibly, and judging from your use case, unless you must have the recent/archived information as part of the URI, it may be simpler to store this information in collections. However, you should read the documentation and evaluate for yourself: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/collections#chapter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read tons of documentation before asking question here. About transactions here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#chapter and here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions# and maybe I missed something, but from what I understood - within MST lock will be held (using "update" trnsaction) on the document, not on the directoy. I've also read this about locks: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/locks#chapter but it raises more questions than answers (can I do it via JavaAPI, etc.). I've also read about collections from your link a

Comment: Will continue in this one: so I've also read about collections (link you posted and just googled) and it's not clear if I should use it for my case and if it gives some benefits. They say that collection info is stored within document and it can be quite slow when changed frequently. That's why I asked actually: will I get some benefit from it for my case?

Comment: 1) During an update or MST transaction, documents will be locked. However, it is also possible to manually lock an entire directory. Be careful with automatic directory creation, however, which can cause locking behavior that you may not expect (and is turned on by default). 2) I don't think there is a simple answer to your question about collections; however, it seems like a good bet if you are trading two updates (delete + insert) for one (collection).

Comment: Where can I read more about this document / directory locking? And maybe about manual locking of entire directory via java API?

Comment: @Anatoliy There is a chapter on locks in the App Dev Guide: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/locks. However, the Java API is a higher level API, and I don't think there is way to manage locks out-of-the box. You will probably need to look into using the resource extension mechanism to do that, which will require some XQuery: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would skip all the hassle with separate directories as well as collections. You would endlessly have to move files around, or changes their properties. It would be much easier to not calculate anything up front, and simply use lastModified property, or something alike, to determine most recent items at run-time.

HTH!

Comment: I think eventually I'll have a lot of documents for each user. Won't it be too slow to calculate the newest 20 each time I need to get them? I was looking at dedicated directories only because of this. But maybe you're right and it's just a preliminary optimization...

Comment: And actually I missed requirement, that if user deleted one of visible to him 20 recent documents - he should see 19. If I have all documents in one directory and just select the newest 20 - this case will be broken (user can have 21 recent document (with only 20 shown to him), then he removes one and still see 20).

Comment: MarkLogic is very fast with searching. It supports dateTime range indexes by default, and can return top 20 ordered by date in sub-sec even for millions of documents.

Comment: What you describe about deleting a doc tend to be the way applications tend to implement this if they aren't backed by a database. Just showing top 20 last modified docs, or optionally showing anything changed since 7 days ago makes perfect sense to me..